# Fetching Values from textField in a custom cell iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have a custom cell in a table View, see below.

[image]

I have two textFields txt1 and txt2 in my custom cell, as seen below

[image]

How can i access the values i enter in each of the text fields so that i can add the values in to seperate Arrays...

the "Addset" button will increment the no of sections of the grouped table View there by incrementing the one more set.

my table view code is as follows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *cellID= @"catogoryCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in nibObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass: [CustomCell class]])
            {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
            }
        }
    }

    //cell.txt1.text = @"0"; 

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells are reusable, so they need a more persistent way to keep their info.

**Method 1:**
You could hold some `UITextField` objects into an array in case you don't want to reuse the textfields as well, and at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you'd only need to set the textfields to their cells such as:

```
cell.txt1 = [textFieldsArray objectAtindex:indexPath.section*2];
cell.txt2 = [textFieldsArray objectAtindex:indexPath.section*2+1]; //txt1 and txt2 properties should have assign
```

**Method 2**:
If you want to reuse the textfields as well I suggest using an array with mutable dictionaries, each dictionary holding the 'settings' for a cell. The textfields will be fully managed by the custom cell (e.g: at the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event update @"txt1" or @"txt2" values from the dictionary attached to the cell).

```
///somewhere in the initialization (in the class holding the tableview)
contentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

///when adding a new cell (e.g: inside the 'Add set' action)
[contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"", @"txt1", @"", @"txt2", nil]];
//add a new cell to the table (the same way you do now when tapping 'Add set')

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...
     [cell attachDictionary:[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    return cell;
}

///anywhere where you'd like to access the values inserted inside a cell
NSMutableDictionary *cell3Content = [contentArray objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *text1 = [cell3Content valueForKey:@"txt1"];
NSString *text2 = [cell3Content valueForKey:@"txt2"];

///CustomCell.m
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if(!self) return nil;
    [txt1 addTarget:self action:@selector(txt1Changed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [txt2 addTarget:self action:@selector(txt2Changed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return self;
}
-(void)attachDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic{
    contentDictionary = dic;
    txt1.text = [contentDictionary valueForKey:@"txt1"];
    txt2.text = [contentDictionary valueForKey:@"txt2"];
}
-(void)txt1Changed:(UITextField *)sender{
    [contentDictionary setValue:txt1.text forKey:@"txt1"];
}
```

Comment: HI Thanks babbiidi, what are the contents in the textFieldarray??

Comment: `textFieldsArray` would hold `UITextField` objects, which can be initialized and set up when 'Add set' is tapped. They can be positioned correctly in the custom cell inside the `txt1` and `txt2` setters of the cell. I personally like the second method better since each cell will handle its content, plus it will use less memory.

Comment: Hi babbidi, i hav tried your code , but somewhere went wrong. The app creashes when the view loads. Could you provide some more stuff please? Is contentArray holds the textField objects??

Comment: No, for the second method `contentArray` contains `NSMutableDictionary` with 2 values at keys: `@"txt1"` and `@"txt2"` (which will be the text inserted in the cell textfields). Also, make sure that in `CustomCell.xib` you have the txt1 and txt2 linked to `IBOutlet UITextfield *txt1;` and `IBOutlet UITextField *txt2` from `CustomCell` class (not the owner, but the cell itself - make its type `CustomCell` in the xib). The code from the second block above (main comment) is about everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the IBOutlet connections in your UITableViewCell subclass, connect them to properties in the File Owner (the viewController), instead of the view itself. That way you'll be able to access them from your viewController (the UItableViewDataSource)