# How to make UITableview with Textfield in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, cell

I want to make a table view with textfields in each cell,

I have a custom class in a swift file:

```
import UIKit

public class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    public func configure(#text: String?, placeholder: String) {
        textField.text = text
        textField.placeholder = placeholder

        textField.accessibilityValue = text
        textField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
    }
}
```

Then in my ViewController I have

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextInputCell") as! TextInputTableViewCell

    cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "Enter some text!")

     text = cell.textField.text

    return cell

}
```

That works well:

[image]

But when the user enters text in the textfield and press the button I want to store the strings of each textfield in an array.
I have tried with

```
text = cell.textField.text
println(text)
```

But it prints nothing like if it was empty

How can I make it work?

Comment: already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344247/fetching-values-from-textfield-in-a-custom-cell-iphone

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your view controller become a UITextFieldDelegate

**View Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var allCellsText = [String]()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.theField.delegate = self // theField is your IBOutlet UITextfield in your custom cell

        cell.theField.text = "Test"

        return cell
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        allCellsText.append(textField.text!)
        println(allCellsText)
    }
}
```

This will always append the data from the textField to the allCellsText array.

Comment: This works! But how can I append textfield.text to the array when the button is pressed? I tried putting: `allCellsText.append(textField.text)
    println(allCellsText)` inside the buttonPressed function but it doesnt identify the textfield

Comment: That can't be done using it with the textField delegate, though you could set some type of condition on your data with the button, or copy the data to a different array.

Comment: @thefredelement In `class ViewController` I have created an instance of TextInputTableViewCell and in ViewDidAppear, I am trying to assign the data from UserDefaults to `var textField` from TextInputTableViewCell, but the assignment fails, unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: But won't this just keep on appending to `allCellsText` whenever `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called?

Answer (score 2):

this method is init the cell,u have not model to save this datas,so

```
text = cell.textfield.text
```

is nothing!
you can init `var textString` in viewcontroller,an inherit UITextFieldDelegate

```
optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
     textString = _textField.text
}
optional func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    return true
}
```

and `cell.textField.text = textString`

Answer (score 2):

create a variable

```
var arrayTextField = [UITextField]()
```

after this in your `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{}`
 add

```
self.arrayTextField.append(textfield)
```

before returning cell, after this to display the values using

```
for textvalue in arrayTextField{
        println(textvalue.text)
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause issues for table rows that might become recycled, or does it retain the memory location of the cell even if you scroll out of view?

Comment: This is a good idea, however as @JoseRamirez pointed out, if you scroll the view, your cellForRowAtIndexPath will append another textview.

Answer (score -1):

So here is a way to do it using the suggestion of having a textfield array. It uses the tag of the textfield to ensure it does not get added multiple times when you scroll.

```
// Assumes that you have a label and a textfield as a part of you tableViewCell

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? BodyStatsTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell.rowLabel.text = bodyTableArray[indexPath.row].rowTitle
    let tagValue = indexPath.row + 100
    var newRow = true
    for textvalue in arrayTextField{
        if textvalue.tag == tagValue {
            newRow = false
        }
    }
    if newRow {
        cell.rowTextField.tag = tagValue
        self.arrayTextField.append(cell.rowTextField)
        cell.rowTextField.text = bodyTableArray[indexPath.row].rowValue
    }
    return cell
}
```

// And then you cam get the values when you want to save with where tag - 100 will be the array index value to update

for textvalue in arrayTextField{
    print(textvalue.text)
}

Comment: After scrolling, this may have different UITextFields in the `arrayTextField` than are visible in the UI.
Also, the other solutions to the question are working correctly without having to resort to this kind of hacks.

Comment: @fishinear, thanks, not sure where I was going with this