# How to Print data from textfield present inside Tableview cell to console on tapping button

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, tableview

I want to print data from textfield present inside the tableview cell to console on clicking a button present outside the tableview.
I am getting data of only single row when i use the IBAction method of button for printing the data.
here is my updated  code for reference.

```
//Deliverview cell
import UIKit
//Protocol
protocol  Delivery {
    func OnClick(index : Int)
}
class DeliveryViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!
    var celldelegate : Delivery?
    var index : IndexPath?
    var data: DeliveryData? {
        didSet {
            updateCell()
        }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        cellTextField.borderStyle = .none
        cellTextField.delegate = self
        // Initialization code
    }
    func updateCell() {
        if let data = data {
            cellTextField.text = data.value
            cellTextField.placeholder = data.placeholder
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pickLocation(_ sender: Any) {
        celldelegate?.OnClick(index: index!.row)
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
extension DeliveryViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ cellTextField: UITextField) {
        deliveryData1.value = cellTextField.text!
    }
}
//View controller
class DeliveryData {
    let placeholder: String
    var value: String = ""
    
    init(_ placeholder: String) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }
}

var deliveryData1: [DeliveryData] = [
    DeliveryData("Name"),
    DeliveryData("Phone"),
    DeliveryData("Email"),
    DeliveryData("order"),
    DeliveryData("Address"),
    DeliveryData("Date"),
    DeliveryData("Description"),
    DeliveryData("Barcode"),
    DeliveryData("Image")
]
```

Comment: are you printing cell1 data ? what you need /

Comment: Yes,I am using cell1 to print data of all row present in the tableview.

Comment: You can print all visible cells textField values ... or you need to store them as TableView cell get reused

Comment: @satyamkumar - see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61462422/6257435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewCell`s are not meant to store state.  As you scroll, the cells will be re-used, and any values they might have (ie, text the user has input) will be lost.

The solution to this is to save out any changes the user has made to a data model.  This can be a class, an array, a dictionary, etc.  In your case, `DeliveryViewCell` will need to conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` in order to be notified when the user has finished editing:

```
extension DeliveryViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //Do something here to save the text...
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of storing the updated text somewhere.  Here is one option, although by no means the only or even best way:

```
//In your cell
var data: DeliveryData? {
    didSet {
        updateCell()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    textField.delegate = self
}

func updateCell() {
    if let data = data {
        textField.text = data.value
        textField.placeholder = data.placeholder
    }
}

extension DeliveryViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        deliveryData?.value = textField.text!
    }
}

//In your view controller
class DeliveryData {
    let placeholder: String
    var value: String = ""

    init(_ placeholder: String) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }
}
var deliveryData: [DeliveryData] = [
    DeliveryData("Name"),
    DeliveryData("Phone"),
    DeliveryData("Email"),
    DeliveryData("order"),
    DeliveryData("Address"),
    DeliveryData("Date"),
    DeliveryData("Description"),
    DeliveryData("Barcode"),
    DeliveryData("Image")
]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = deliveryTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DeliveryViewCell

    cell.data = deliveryData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

@IBAction func tapSaveData(_ sender: Any) {
    for data in deliveryData {
        print(data.value)
    }
}
```

This also has the added benefit of restoring any text the user types in when a cell gets scrolled back into view.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer.but i am stuck in textFieldDidEndEditing function and not able to access the attribute 'value' of deliverData,due to which i am getting index out of range while printing data in tapSaveData function.

Comment: Update your question with your newest code and we can take a look.

Comment: Hi I have updated the code in the question.I am getting this error : Value of type '[DeliveryData]' has no member 'value'  when using this code in deliveryviewcell : extension DeliveryViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ cellTextField: UITextField) {
        deliveryData1.value = cellTextField.text!
    }
} P.s : I have tried to put Deliverviewdata class and its variable in the viewcontroller as well as creating a different class for DeliveryViewData,but unable to resolve the issue

Comment: The DeliveryData class can be defined in the same file as the view controller, or a separate file. Just make sure to define it outside of the view controller class. 
As for the error, in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` function you should be accessing `data` not `deliveryData1`: `data?.value = cellTextField.text!`.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you described the question I believe you are trying to print the value of a text field associated with a specific cell. You have several ways of achieving that.

### Method 1 (easiest)

The easiest for beginners in this scenario is the following.
Change your cellForRowAt to do the following:

```swift
let cell = deliveryTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DeliveryViewCell
cell.cellTextField.placeholder = deliveryData[indexPath.row]
//button refers to the button Outlet you have or should create.
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row 
return cell
```

Then change your button's action to be:

```swift
@IBAction func tapSaveData(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let row = sender.tag //The tag you saved when dequeuing the cell
    let cell1 = deliveryTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0)) as! DeliveryViewCell

    print(cell1.cellTextField.text!)
}
```

### Method 2

You can simply use a closure inside the cell.

So lets say this is part of your custom cell:

```swift
... your code

var onTextFieldEndEditing: ((String?) -> Void)?
    
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //when editing is done.
    onTextFieldEndEditing?(textField.text)
}
```

Then, in your cellForRowAt:

```swift
let cell = deliveryTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DeliveryViewCell
cell.cellTextField.placeholder = deliveryData[indexPath.row]
cell.onTextFieldEndEditing = { [weak self] text in
    print(text)
}
return cell
```

In method 2 you don't need the @IBAction for the button anymore or the button itself.
If you still wish to invoke the print on button tap you can simply create an @IBAction inside the cell itself and then call the closure when the button is tapped instead of when the text field ends editing.
Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear answer,however i am looking to place my button outside the tableview and in this case it is not possible for me to use cell.button.tag = indexpath.row as outlet from button cannot be created to tableview cell in this case.